# comparing integer with multiple conditions in powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, compare

Sorry for the "stupid" question but I'm going crazy!
I need to understand if a variable exist and, if exist, checking also if its value isn't 0.
I can use multiple conditions, or I've to use multiple statements like elseif?

```
[int]$AllDbAvail = 0 #(in this case I've defined variable)
[int]$int0 = 0
if ( ( Test-Path !variable:AllDbAvail ) -or ( $AllDbAvail -ne $int0 ) ) {"ok"} else {"not ok"}

PS >not ok
```

Another test with @Mathias approch:

```
PS >  Remove-Variable AllDbAvail
PS > if ( ( Test-Path variable:AllDbAvail ) -and ( $AllDbAvail -ne $int0 ) ) {"ok"} else {"not ok"}
not ok
PS > [int]$AllDbAvail = 0
PS > if ( ( Test-Path variable:AllDbAvail ) -and ( $AllDbAvail -ne $int0 ) ) {"ok"} else {"not ok"}
not ok
```

---

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  3770
```

tried also on:

```
Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      2      1
```

Same result.

[image: something strange]

For powershell `"number 0"` isn't a value! Or better, is a value only in certain circumstances!

And an `int` can be created without the `[int]` prefix, if number 0 have to be a string needs to be expressed with double quotes `"0"`:

[image: int vs string]

Comment: `if ($AllDbAvail)` should get you your expected results if `AllDbAvail` is always a number. It will return true if you pass a non-empty string and other non-integer cases but for the code you've shown, this should be enough.

Comment: Looks like you'll want to change `-or` to `-and`

Comment: Hi @NicoNekoru, yes `$AllDbAvail` will be always an INT!

Comment: @ilRobby If you _know_ that `$AllDbAvail` is defined and has a value - why are you testing whethre it exists?

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, `$AllDbAvail` may not exist, I'm just writing a script where I've to manage two eventualities! During my test seems that the PS's core consider only the first variable with both operators `-and/-or`...

Comment: But you just said it will always be an integer? How can you claim that if it may not exist? Why not declare `$AllDbAvail` as a parameter, that way you'll be sure it exists

Comment: If exist, it is always an INT and may increments during script... if not exist, will exist another variable

Comment: But is usefull to know that a non existent variable will evaluate to `$null`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `!` from the variable provider path and change `-or` to `-and`:

```
if ((Test-Path variable:AllDbAvail) -and ($AllDbAvail -ne 0)) {
  "ok"
}
else {
  "not ok"
}
```

That being said, having to test for the *existence* of a variable is a bit of a code smell - you might want to rethink your approach :)

As [Nico points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76876372/comparing-integer-with-multiple-conditions-in-powershell#comment135525801_76876372) in the comments, you can simplify the condition significantly:

```
if ($AllDbAvail) {
  "ok"
}
else {
  "not ok"
}
```

A variable that hasn't been assigned to will evaluate to `$null` - and both `$null` and the integer value `0` will in turn evaluate to `$false` when converted to a boolean.

---

With regards to your "second test", I'm not really sure what to say - it's behaving exactly as expected.

Did you try specifying a non-zero value?

[image]

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, I've edited the post, please look at 2° test, the one with variable defined, I would expect an "ok"...
Am I confused here?

Comment: @ilRobby You forgot to define `$int0` (do yourself a favor and just compare to a literal `0` instead)

Comment: Pardon! I'm using the same shell/session, `$int0` already defined!

Comment: @ilRobby Why are you expecting it so say "ok" when the value is `0`? I thought the whole point was to test that the variable existed and was _not_ 0?

Comment: Mmmm... if exist and not equal to 0, both conditions matches and should give "ok"... no?

Comment: @ilRobby If you set `$AllDbAvail = 0` then the "not equal to 0" condition is obviously not satisfied

Comment: Please forgive me Mathias! I got confused...

Comment: Ok, I've understand but, there is something strange Mathias, please, look my 3° example

Comment: @ilRobby I don't understand what you're asking me. You've updated your post to show PowerShell behaving the way its designed - what's the question? `0` is a value - it just happens to be the only numerical value that converts to `$false` instead of `$true` when converted to a boolean

Comment: Oh,  just to share a thought! It's not strange for you?

Comment: @ilRobby No, it's not strange to me that a programming language would treat `0` as "falsy" and any non-zero value as "truthy". In fact that's very common - Lisp, C, C++, Java, C#, Python, Perl, Lua, all follow this boolean conversion logic more or less.

Comment: I apologize! I'm a self-taught! Thanks again!

Comment: @ilRobby You're most welcome! But it sounds like you should teach yourself some more languages, get a broader perspective :)